# How to filter custom post types by Category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type for podcasts but I can't get the category filter to work.  I created custom Taxonomies called Podcast Categories.  When I click on one of the categories they all still show.  Each podcast added has a different category.  I can not figure out how to make it work so any help would be so appreciated!!

This is my functions.php file -

```
//Podcasts
function podcast_custom_post_type () {
    $labels = array (
        'name' => 'Podcasts',
        'singular_name' => 'Podcast',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Podcast',
        'all_items' => 'All Podcasts',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add A Podcast',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Podcast',
        'new_item' => 'New Podcast',
        'view_item' => 'View Podcast',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcast' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
    //'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
register_post_type('podcast', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'podcast_custom_post_type');

function podcast_custom_taxonomies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Podcast Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Podcast Category',
        'search_items' => 'Search Podcast Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Podcast Category',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Podcast Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Podcast Category:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Podcast Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Podcast Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Podcast Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Podcast Category',
        'menu_name' => 'Podcast Categories'
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcast_category' )
    );

    register_taxonomy('podcast_category', array('podcast'), $args);
}
add_action( 'init' , 'podcast_custom_taxonomies' );



add_action('pre_get_posts', 'altering_podcast_archive_query', 99);
function altering_podcast_archive_query($query)
{
    if (
        is_post_type_archive('podcast') 
        && 
        get_query_var('orderby')
       ) 
    {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('orderby')),
            )
        );
        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    };
};
```

And this is my theme page I created -

```
<?php
    /*Template Name: News & Media */
    get_header();
?>

<div class="singlewidth">
<div id="primary">

<form method='GET'>
  <select name='orderby' id='orderby'>
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
      'hide_empty' => 'false'
    ]);
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
    ?>

      <option value='<?php echo $term->slug; ?>' <?php echo selected(sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']), $term->slug); ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
  <button type='submit'>Filter</button>
</form>

<div class="podcasts">



<ul>


 <?php
    query_posts(array(
       'post_type' => 'podcast'
    )); ?>
    <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   



<li>
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { /* loades the post's featured thumbnail, requires Wordpress 3.0+ */ echo '<div class="featured-thumb clearfix">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>'; } ?>


<div class="podcasttext">
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'azurebasic' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


<?php if( get_field('podcast_text') ): ?>
    <?php the_field('podcast_text'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="podcastplayer">
<?php if( get_field('add_podcast') ): ?>
    <?php the_field('add_podcast'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

</li>

<?php 
endwhile; 
?>

</ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php  get_footer();  ?>
```

this is the webpage it's on -
https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/resources/news-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Connect taxonomy `podcast_category` to custom post type `podcast`
- Change the select form field name for `orderby` (if possible)
- Add (the newly named) `orderby` parameter to WP_Query for use as a filter
- Avoid `query_posts()`

Explanations and updated code samples are below.

## Connect taxonomy `podcast_category` to custom post type `podcast`

[WP Docs for register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) say that:

> any taxonomy connections should be registered via the $taxonomies argument

When calling `register_taxonomy()` set the `$object_type` argument to `null` (see wordpress.stackexchange.com answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-object-type-truly-required-with-register-taxonomy)), and use the `'taxonomies'` property in the call to `register_post_type()` to connect the `podcast_category` taxonomy to the `podcast` custom post type. While there are other ways to accomplish the same thing, this approach is easy to understand.

### Code in the `podcast_custom_taxonomies()` function would need to change from this:

```
    register_taxonomy('podcast_category', array('podcast'), $args);
}
```

...to this...

```
    register_taxonomy('podcast_category', null, $args);
}
```

### Code in the `podcast_custom_post_type()` function would need to change from this:

```
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
    //'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
```

...to this...

```
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
    'taxonomies' => array('podcast_category', 'category', 'post_tag'),
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
```

---

## Change the select form field name for `orderby` (if possible)

Using `orderby` as an argument in `get_query_var()` can cause problems. **orderby** is an existing WP_Query [public query variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) used to sort the list of posts. Your code seems to use `orderby` not as a sort key, but as a filter. When your code calls `get_query_var('orderby')` it is retrieving the existing [WP_Query parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) value for **orderby**, not the value for `orderby` submitted by the HTML form.

The HTML form select options are *podcast categories* used as a *filter*. To reduce confusion, I suggest changing the HTML form select tag name and ID to `podcast_category_filter`.

---

## Add (the newly named) `orderby` parameter to WP_Query for use as a filter

Assuming `orderby` has been changed to `podcast_category_filter`, the `get_query_var()` function can be called to get the value submitted by the HTML form only after the field `podcast_category_filter` has been added to the list of WP_Query public query variables. Once added to the list, WordPress will know that when it sees  `podcast_category_filter` in the URL (e.g. `https://example.com/podcast?podcast_category_filter=sports`), `podcast_category_filter` and its value should be added to WP_Query. The value for `podcast_category_filter` can then be retrieved using `get_query_var('podcast_category_filter')`.

To add `podcast_category_filter` to the list of WP_Query public query variables, use the [query_vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/#example) filter hook in your theme or plugin:

```
function myplugin_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'podcast_category_filter';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_query_vars' );
```

---

## Avoid `query_posts()`

Please note this warning from the [WordPress Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) on the use of the `query_posts()` function:

> Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. [...] This must not be used within the WordPress Loop.

WordPress suggests using the [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action within [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

To avoid `query_posts()` changes to your code could look like this:

### Delete this from your theme page:

```
query_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'podcast'
)); ?>
```

### Remove the `pre_get_posts` action hook:

For the purpose of producing a list of posts filtered by a `podcast_category`, `pre_get_posts` is not needed. `pre_get_posts` modifies the Main Loop (primary) query. The filtered post list is not produced from the Main Loop, but from a secondary loop. The secondary loop comes from `$podcast_query` in the updated code sample below.

## Updated code

### Add to functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * functions.php (partial)
 *
 * To be included in the (child) theme's functions.php file.
 */

//Podcasts
function podcast_custom_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Podcast Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Podcast Category',
        'search_items' => 'Search Podcast Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Podcast Category',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Podcast Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Podcast Category:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Podcast Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Podcast Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Podcast Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Podcast Category',
        'menu_name' => 'Podcast Categories'
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // Make available in Edit Post block options (for testing).
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcast_category' )
    );

    \register_taxonomy('podcast_category', null, $args);
}

// Priority must be a lower number than register_post_type.
// register_taxonomy must be called before register_post_type.
add_action( 'init', 'podcast_custom_taxonomies', 10 );


function podcast_custom_post_type () {
    $labels = array (
        'name' => 'Podcasts',
        'singular_name' => 'Podcast',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Podcast',
        'all_items' => 'All Podcasts',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add A Podcast',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Podcast',
        'new_item' => 'New Podcast',
        'view_item' => 'View Podcast',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'podcast' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('podcast_category', 'category', 'post_tag'),
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );

    \register_post_type('podcast', $args);
}

// Priority must be a higher number than register_taxonomy.
// register_post_type must be called after register_taxonomy.
add_action( 'init', 'podcast_custom_post_type', 20 );


function myplugin_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'podcast_category_filter';
    return $qvars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_query_vars' );
```

### <child_theme_root_folder>/page-template/template-podcast-newsandmedia.php

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: News & Media
    Template Post Type: podcast, post, page
*/

/**
 * File: <child_theme_root_folder>/page-template/template-podcast-newsandmedia.php
 *
 * The file name follows this convention: page-template/template-<custom_post_type>-<filename>.php
 */

\get_header();
?>

<div class="singlewidth">
<div id="primary">

<?php
$filter = \get_query_var( 'podcast_category_filter' );

// If you don't need special class names or custom attributes in the
// select or option tags consider using wp_dropdown_categories()
// @see {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/}
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'          => 'podcast_category',
    'selected'          => \sanitize_text_field( $filter ),
    'name'              => 'podcast_category_filter',
    'hide_empty'        => false,  // Set to true to avoid an empty result from the filter.
    'orderby'           => 'name', // Default. Sort list alphabetically.
    'value_field'       => 'slug',
    'echo'              => false,  // Set to true to echo the HTML directly rather than save the HTML to a variable.
    'show_option_all'   => 'All podcasts',
    'option_none_value' => 0       // Value to use when no category is selected. Same value as 'All podcasts'.
);
$select_category_html = \wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>

<form method='GET'>
    <?php echo $select_category_html ?>
    <button type='submit'>Filter</button>
</form>

<div class="podcasts">

<ul>
    <?php $tax_query = array();

    // Be careful here. When the HTML form select option "All podcasts" is selected
    // the number zero (0) is assigned to the form field "podcast_category_filter". When
    // this happens, get_query_var( 'podcast_category_filter' ) returns zero which is implicitly
    // cast as the Boolean value "false". Although unnecessary, it is a good idea to explicitly
    // test for the conditions that causes the if-statement to fail.
    // You may want to add error checking here to test that 'podcast_category_filter' is an
    // exact match with a valid podcast category name.
    if ( ( 0 != $filter ) && is_string( $filter ) && ( '' != $filter ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => \sanitize_text_field( $filter ),
            )
        );
    }

    // Create a secondary query to avoid using the main query.
    // You may need to update the $args argument to handle pagination
    // if you want to avoid a very long list in the results.
    // @see {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters}
    $args = array_merge(
        array( 'post_type' => 'podcast' ),
        array( 'tax_query' => $tax_query )
    );
    $podcast_query = new \WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $podcast_query->have_posts() ) : $podcast_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                // loads the post's featured thumbnail, requires Wordpress 3.0+
                if ( \has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<div class="featured-thumb clearfix">';
                    \the_post_thumbnail();
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>

                <div class="podcasttext">
                    <h2 class="entry-title">
                        <a
                            href="<?php \the_permalink(); ?>"
                            title="<?php printf(
                                \esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'azurebasic' ),
                                \the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
                            ); ?>"
                            rel="bookmark"
                        >
                            <?php \the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>

                    <?php
                    if( get_field('podcast_text') ) :
                        the_field('podcast_text');
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="podcastplayer">
                    <?php
                    if( get_field('add_podcast') ) :
                        the_field('add_podcast');
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php
        endwhile;

        // Reset global $post variable back to the main query.
        \wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        // Display something if there are no posts.
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php \get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kofeigen!  I made all of the changes but my posts aren't showing on the page now.  I did change the pre_get_posts action hook to what you suggested and it gave me a critical error.  I found that this piece is what gave me the error - $query->set('post_type', 'podcast');  when I took that out the critical error was gone.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You totally rock Kofeigen!! It works perfectly!!!  The only thing is the podcast categories show twice on the admin post page.  What do I do  to remove one of those podcast category section and also the regular categories section?  I would just like to have only the podcast category option.    I can't thank you enough for taking the time to explain everything and work on a solution for me!!   Also if on another page I only want to show the Presidents Message podcasts category how do I do that?

Comment: Great. Glad it works. The problem with the admin post page sounds unrelated to the title of the original question. You may wish to open a new StackOverflow question and post a screen shot to show exactly where the problem is. About the Presidents Message podcasts category, I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. But, if I were to guess, you could try a URL something like this: https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/podcast_category/presidents-message. A custom design for this page could be handled by an archive template file named <child_theme_root>/taxonomy-presidents-message.php

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  So when creating a new post there are 2 squares to choose the Podcast Category. So both squares say "Podcast Categories"  and they both have checkboxes to choose either the "Presidents Message" category or the "Podcast Series" category.  I have to check each square in both options for it to show on the front end for the correct category.  Here is a link to a screenshot https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/Screenshot%202023-11-06%20at%207.51.36%20AM.pdf. The left side also shows Podcast Categories & Podcast Category.  How can I remove those duplicates?

Comment: Looks like two taxonomies were registered with similar names. The left-side admin menu names show "Podcast Category" and "Podcast Categories". Your original StackOverflow question uses `'menu_name' => 'Podcast Categories'`. Can you check the `wp_term_taxonomy` database table to see if the `term_id` for *Presidents Message* or *Podcast Series* shows up twice? And, if it shows up twice, what is the `taxonomy` for each instance? Is there any chance you have two calls to `register_taxonomy()` somewhere in your code? Are your taxonomies managed by any of your plugins?

Comment: Ahhh I totally forgot I had tried with Advanced Custom Fields.  I deleted that taxonomy and the duplication is gone.  Thank you so much!  Everything works perfect now!  The only question I have is when I click to choose the category of podcasts everything works but the page jumps back up to the top so you have to scroll back down to view the podcasts.  Is there a way to fix that so it stays where the podcasts are?   Here's the page so you can see what I mean -  https://baptist.tfm-dev.com/resources/news-resources  It's password protected for now so this is the password - TFMRocks!

Comment: Also does the category query always have to be a dropdown or can it be buttons that you click on instead?

Comment: Hi. Not sure if this will work for you, but it worked for me. Try replacing this line: `<form method='GET'>` with: `<a name="podcasts"></a><form action="#podcasts" method='GET'>`. `<a name="podcasts"></a>` is an anchor. The page will jump to that location if `#podcasts` is at the end of the URL. You can change `podcasts` to whatever you like.

Comment: No, you do not have to use a dropdown. You can use any design. You just need to be aware of all the changes required to accommodate the design. For example, multiple-select form fields like checkboxes require form field names that work with how PHP recognizes arrays. The `query_vars` filter hook would need to be updated. You also have to change how `template-podcast-newsandmedia.php` displays selected vs. non-selected options. You'll need to return to your original idea of using `get_terms()` instead of `wp_dropdown_categories()`, and then lay out buttons in an array of rows and columns.

Comment: Hi Kofeigen!  That worked it stopped loading back at the top of the page!  Thank you so much for all of your help!!  I so appreciate it!!

Comment: You're welcome. I removed my comment about the test code since I've copied it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```php
 <?php

  // Query Arguments
  $args = array(
    //
    // your custom post type
    //
    'post_type' => 'podcast',
    //
    // your taxonomy info to filter
    //
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        //
        // your custom taxonomy
        //
        'taxonomy' => 'podcast_category',
        //
        // eg. we filter by slug
        //
        'field'    => 'slug',
        //
        // replace 'the-slug' with your target slugs to filter
        //
        'terms'    => array('the-slug'),  
      ),
    ),
  );

  query_posts($args);
?>
```

That's all, if I understand what you are asking.

I am sure that there are hundreds of such posts to solve this.

Comment: Thank you!  Would I put that on the theme page or in the functions file?

Comment: For your current style, you should put inside your theme page. Practically, replace your "query_posts(array('post_type' => 'podcast'));" with above.

Comment: Thank you!  I added the code but it's not filtering when I choose a category.

Comment: Well, this is far away from the point. You need to apply the current selected term slug dynamically by get_query_var('term').